# run step in github actions when command is not found

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to setup X if X is not found in github action. X being anything like java, node, etc.

To do so I currently use:

```
    - name: Check java found
      run: java --version
      id: check_java
      shell: bash
      continue-on-error: true

    - name: Install java
      if: steps.check_java.outcome == 'failure'
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: "zulu"
        java-version: "17.x"
        cache: "gradle"
```

While this works, it outputs an error `Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Is there a way to do the above without an error written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your first step with something like this, and then use the step output:

```yaml
    - name: Check java found
      id: check_java
      run: |
        if java --version; then
            echo "installed=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        else
            echo "installed=false" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        fi

    - name: Install java
      if: steps.check_java.outputs.installed == 'false'
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: "zulu"
        java-version: "17.x"
        cache: "gradle"
```

Because the command is in an `if` clause, it won't trigger the "error on exit" condition.